# Refreshing page on Google Cloud App Engine throws 404

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have an Angular 6 app built and deployed to Google Cloud App Engine, which is functioning correctly. However, any time the browser is refreshed with a route other than the root of the app, we are getting a 404.

Here is our app.yaml file:

```
runtime: nodejs8

handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: dist/song/index.html
    upload: dist/song/index.html
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*)
    static_files: dist/song/\1
    upload: dist/song/(.*)
    secure: always

  - url: /dashboard
    static_files: dist/song/index.html
    upload: dist/song/index.html
    secure: always
```

The error is a 404 saying "Static file referenced by handler not found: song/dashboard/allshoppers"

So, it's looking for a static file in a directory structure, but this is a route within our Angular app.

Comment: UPDATE: The accepted answer below would work, however in the end we resolved the problem  by rather than deploying the Angular app, we ran ng-build locally, then deployed the static assets to the cloud. (with runtime: nodejs10 now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem and tried the answer above with no luck. After a lot of trial and error I ended up with the app.yaml below. That one works for my setup using Google Cloud Build to deploy to Google App Engine directly.

As a bonus it also redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS, and skip files not usually needed.

I'm sure there might be more efficient ways to do this, but once I got it working I didn't dare change it any more.

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
  - url: /(.+\.js)
    static_files: dist/project/\1
    upload: dist/project/(.+\.js)
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

  - url: /(.+\.css)
    static_files: dist/project/\1
    upload: dist/project/(.+\.css)
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

  - url: /(.+\.png)
    static_files: dist/project/\1
    upload: dist/project/(.+\.png)
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

  - url: /(.+\.jpg)
    static_files: dist/project/\1
    upload: dist/project/(.+\.jpg)
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

  - url: /(.+\.gif)
    static_files: dist/project/\1
    upload: dist/project/(.+\.gif)
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

  - url: /(.+\.svg)
    static_files: dist/project/\1
    upload: dist/project/(.+\.svg)
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

  - url: /favicon.ico
    static_files: dist/project/favicon.ico
    upload: dist/project/favicon.ico
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

  - url: /(.+\.json)
    static_files: dist/project/\1
    upload: dist/project/(.+\.json)
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

  - url: /(.+)
    static_files: dist/project/index.html
    upload: dist/project/index.html
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

  - url: /
    static_files: dist/project/index.html
    upload: dist/project/index.html
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

skip_files:
  - e2e/
  - node_modules/
  - src/
  - ^(.*/)?\..*$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.md$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.yaml$
  - ^LICENSE
```

Comment: I tried the above and it works for me but the only thing is on every refresh it get redirected from the home page. Any workaround for that or am I missing something here.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to redirect every request to index.html to let the Angular router handle everything.

```
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/song/index.html
  upload: dist/song/index.html
  http_headers:
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Comment: hello Sorry for asking this much late but it is not working for me can you help me please

Comment: @DShultz What did your app.yaml end up looking like? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Kenneth The same yaml, however, in the end rather than deploying the Angular app, we ran ng-build locally, then deployed the static assets to the cloud. (with runtime: nodejs10 now)

Answer (score 0):

```
service: default
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    static_files: <your folder>/index.html
    upload: <your folder>/index.html
  - url: /
    static_dir: <your folder>
```

Just use the url `/.*` to add a wildcard route to always redirect to your index.html